# Creating file with CreateFile function results in write protected file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have been trying to write a file in path returned by **SHGetFolderPath** . But as File Is created, it has been given Write Protected. Following is my Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hfile;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    char dataBuffer[] = "Some data to write here";
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA,NULL,0, szPath)))    
    {
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        PathAppend(szPath,TEXT("lpa"));
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        PathAppend(szPath,TEXT("config"));
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        CreateDirectory(szPath, NULL);
        PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("lpa.config"));
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        hfile = CreateFile(szPath,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_NEW,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
        /*WriteFile(hfile,dataBuffer,(DWORD)strlen(dataBuffer),&dwBytesWritten,NULL);
        std::cout << szPath <<std::endl;*/
    }

}
```

The code creates a file in **C:\ProgramData\lpa\config\lpa.config** but editing the file pops up dialog saying WriteProtection. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have administrative permissions on your machine? I just compiled your program under Visual Studio 2013, executed it. I can edit the file. I didn't face any issue.

Comment: I am running Visual Studio as Administrator. Is this bringing errors?

Comment: Yes, When you run VS instance with Admin privileges, special permissions are assigned to the created file. Either run as the program as Non-Admin or use SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR carefully.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446595.aspx

the example in the link shows how a registry key is created, you can put CreateFile() instead.

Comment: The Code when Run in Visual studio 2010(Administrator running) did create file but editing it manually showed write protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using  **CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA** instead of **CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA** . I have the modified code given as below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hfile;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    char dataBuffer[] = "Some data to write here";
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,NULL,0, szPath))) 
    {
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        PathAppend(szPath,TEXT("lpa"));
        if(!CreateDirectory(szPath, NULL))
        {
            std::cout << "Create directory failed" <<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        PathAppend(szPath,TEXT("config"));
        if(!CreateDirectory(szPath, NULL))
        {
            std::cout << "Create directory failed" <<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("lpa.config"));
        std::cout << szPath << std::endl;
        hfile = CreateFile(szPath,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,CREATE_NEW,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
        WriteFile(hfile,dataBuffer,(DWORD)strlen(dataBuffer),&dwBytesWritten,NULL);
        std::cout << szPath <<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, When you run VS instance with Admin privileges, special permissions are assigned to the created file. Either run as the program as Non-Admin or use SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR so that other user can access the file.

[Creating a Security Descriptor for a New Object in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446595.aspx)

the example in the link shows how a registry key is created, you can put CreateFile() instead.

Comment: I did solved the issue when I used **CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA** insted of **CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA**

Comment: Obviously, you won't face issue when using LOCAL_APPDATA. That CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA refers to a folder containing application data for all users.

See here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I was facing write protected when used CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA. But using CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA fixed the issue.